# copy public_html via ftp on linux

Tags: linux, ftp

I am trying to copy about 1000 files located within public_html (and a few directories within it) . I have tried a few commands suggested but can't seem to get it to work.

This one in particular looks interesting:

```
-wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=5 -nc ftp://user:pass@server//absolute/path/to/directory
```

But the problem is, it would copy all the files (even from folders within) and place them in the same dir where its being downloaded instead of keeping the dir structure. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

please try wget -r --no-parent ftp://user:pass@server//absolute/path/to/directory

Comment: Thanksf or that. For now, I just used "lftp" to mirror the files and it worked great!. I'd try this again in a few hours while moving another account.